# Elementary OS is running extremely slow and it's almost unusable

Tags: release-hera, system

I would say that I have a pretty good computer, so that shouldn't be a problem:

- 16GB RAM
- i5-6600
- RX480 8GB(i did install the drivers)

Some examples of it running poorly are Discord crashing all the time, sometimes windows take more than 10 seconds to open, the "right-click menu" when let's say I right-click a file is awful, it is so slow that I can't even select the option I want properly.

It is overall really slow.

What I tried to do is install Wingpanel System Monitor to check my CPU and RAM usage but it was fine, like CPU is at 35% most of the time and RAM as well is on low usage.

I freshly installed Elementary OS a week ago and I don't have that many Apps. Major ones are Discord, VS Code, RubyMine and WebStorm and that's pretty much it of big apps.

It is even running slow when I'm only running Discord.

Comment: Where did you install it? SSD, HDD, or flash drive?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Right now my CPU usage is near zero, RAM at 17%, but completely unresponsive. Takes half a minute to maximize/minimize a window. No zombie processes. Installed in a SSD @nate